# Why does this Möbius transformation and complex ratio equality result in a different permutation than expected?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, mobius-transformation

Assume that $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$, and $z_4$ are all distinct complex numbers and $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ is defined to be a Möbius transformation. If $f(z_1)=0$, $f(z_2)=1$ and $f(z_3)=∞$, then show that $f(z_4)=(z_1,z_2;z_3,z_4)$.

I have tried using two different $S_4$ permutations of cross ratios:
$(z_1,z_2;z_3,z_4)=\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)} \rightarrow f(z_4)=\frac{1}{1-\lambda}$,
$(z_1,z_2;z_3,z_4)=\frac{(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_3-z_2)} \rightarrow f(z_4)=\frac{1}{λ}$,

where $\lambda = (z_1,z_2;z_3,z_4)$.

Why is $f(z_4)$ not equal to $\lambda$?

Also, there seems to be more than one definition of $\lambda$ on the web, one for the reals and another for the complex, which I don't know why BTW.

I'm starting to think that maybe there's something wrong with the question itself, as appeared in exercise 2.10. [Treisman 2009](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.1205). A typo maybe? Or am I missing something subtle here?

Comment: The exercise is not correct. If $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are mapped to $0, 1, \infty$, then, with the definition of the cross-ratio given in the text,
$$f(z) = \frac {(z_2 - z_3) (z - z_1)} {(z_2 - z_1) (z - z_3)} =
(z, z_2; z_1, z_3) =
\frac 1 {1 - (z_1, z_2; z_3, z)}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I needed someone to say this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consult the Wikipedia page, for instance.  "Möbius transformation - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation

That cross-ratios are invariant under Mobius transformations doesn't imply that $f(z_4)=\lambda$.

Furthermore, the definition of cross-ratio that I found there was the first one.

Comment: Good thing you pointed that out. The cross-ratio invariance doesn't necessarily imply that $f(z_4)=λ$. I found that, however, $f(z_1)=(z_1,z_2;z_3,z_4)$ when: $z_2$ is mapped to $1$, $z_3$ to $0$ and $z_4$ to $∞$. Also, I used the definition of cross-ratio as found on wiki, that is, the first one.